# Поиск в пределах одной разметки

Tags: android, поиск, разметка

Есть xml с разметкой, на ней много кнопок, обработка каждой приводит к определенному действию
Требуется организовать поиск в пределах этого xml таким образом, чтобы в результатах поиска можно было нажать найденную кнопку и получить отработку искомого действия
Есть ли рабочие примеры такого поиска?

Comment: Не очень понятно что вам нужно и зачем. Вас не устраивает получение ссылки на вьюху по её ID?

Comment: Нужно просто окно поиска на странице приложения, чтобы можно было найти нужный элемент на ней и отобразить его в результатах поиска

Comment: Ну... Эту задачу можно усложнять очень долго, не знаю насколько сложно вам её надо решить. Как насчёт списка пар `Название кнопки, например: "следующий"` и `ID` оной? И вот по этому списку и искать?

Comment: Решить, конечно, нужно максимально просто... Вообще, на самом деле, нужно просто сделать приложение с поискам. Приложение представляет собой экран с кнопками на нем. Пока это разметка с кнопками, активность, которая отрабатывает эти кнопки... Возможно можно как то иначе структурировать все приложение, чтобы и задача отрабатывания кнопок решалась, и поиск на странице работал...

Comment: Думаю, предложенный выше способ вам должен подойти.

Comment: Еще бы понять, как это реализовать в виде кода )))

Comment: Ну... Создайте переменную `List<Pair<String, @IdRes Integer> buttonsList = new ArrayList<>()`. Наполните её: `buttonsList.add("Далее", R.id.nextButtonId)`. Теперь можете как-то что-то искать. Например ищите `Далее` - получаете `ID` нужно кнопки. По ID её находите в разметке и что-то с ней делаете.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!